# Define ".setSeriesNames" as a specific column from my Feature Collection when charting in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, features, chart, feature-collection

I have an asset imported from a shapefile in GEE. It is a feature collection with which I wish to chart a time series. The lines from each feature are labelled as system:index. See labelling of picture below and ignore the amount of features, it's a WIP.

[image]

I want them to be labelled as the "fid" column in my asset's table. See picture below (column to the right).

[image]

Can this be done with .setSeriesNames or some other argument?

Code for chart is the usual, found below.

```
//// Plot results
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  s2CloudMasked, 
  fc,
  ee.Reducer.median(),
  'NDVI',10)
  .setChartType('LineChart')
  .setSeriesNames([])
  .setOptions({
    interpolateNulls: true,
    lineWidth: 1,
    pointSize: 3,
    title: 'NDVI monthly G3',
    hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
    vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
    series: {0:{color: 'red'}
    }
  });
print(chart)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I only needed to specify the seriesProperty parameter as "fid":

```
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: s2CloudMasked,
  band: 'NDVI',
  regions: fc,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  seriesProperty: 'fid',
})
```

Comment: yeey you are a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 'fid' is unique for each feature, you can simply assign it to the system:index on each feature and it'll get used as the series label.  But to do that you have to convert the collection to a list (so that system:index isn't assigned by the collection) and back.  You may or may not also need to convert the fid to a string (using ee.Number.format)

```
fc = ee.FeatureCollection(fc.toList(100).map(function(f) {
  f = ee.Feature(f)
  return f.set("system:index", f.get('fid'))
}))
```

Comment: Can you update the code for use w/ ee.Number.format? I'm a complete beginner and tried my best alone but no cigar ("ee.Number.Format is not a function").